# Disable button on a long operation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

During a long operation I would like to disable a button and clear a text block.

On button click the event is handled in full before painting the screen so the  button is never visibly disabled

```
private bool btnEnabled = true;
public bool BtnEnabled
{
    get { return btnEnabled; }
    set
    {
        if (value == btnEnabled)
            return;
        btnEnabled = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("BtnEnabled");
    }
}
private string results = "start";
public string Results
{
    get { return results; }
    set
    {
        if (value == results)
            return;
        results = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Results");
    }
}

private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BtnEnabled = false;
    Results = string.Empty;
    // whould like to displany wait spinner
    LongProcess();
    BtnEnabled = true;
}
private void LongProcess()
{
    //database query
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Results = "this is the results";
}
```

**How do I get the button to disable during the long event?**

Problem I have is users get frustrated and start clicking and those clicks are all in the queue and get processed.

Comment: Use background processing to run the long code. This will allow the UI thread to update and show the change to disable the button.

Comment: I think you can try async & await for achieving this.

Comment: @Rennie yes await seems to do the trick

Comment: @Paparazzi I was posting the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I ended up with

```
private async void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    BtnEnabled = false;
    Results = string.Empty;
    // whould like to displany wait spinner
    //LongProcess();
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    try
    {
        //cts.Cancel(); just for test
        string result = await WaitAsynchronouslyAsync(cts.Token);
        //string result = await WaitSynchronously();

        BtnEnabled = true;
        Results = result;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Results = "Operation canceled";  // this is not called
    }
    cts = null;
}
// The following method runs asynchronously. The UI thread is not
// blocked during the delay. You can move or resize the Form1 window 
// while Task.Delay is running.
public async Task<string> WaitAsynchronouslyAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    //DataBaseQuery();  // this just runs async
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    //await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync(ct);
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    return "Finished";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, you can use something like this to make the UI process the messages (after you set the button to disabled):

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
             DispatcherPriority.Background, 
             new Action(delegate { })
           );
```

Or the more complete:

```
public void DoEvents()
{
    DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
}

public object ExitFrame(object f)
{
    ((DispatcherFrame)f).Continue = false;
    return null;
}
```

Then again, **this is not recommended** (it's the equivalent of using `Application.DoEvents()` on Winforms, which has many caveats and should be avoided like the plague unless you know what you are doing). Long intensive operations should just not be done on the UI thread, or you could use `async/await` if they are not CPU intensive.

Comment: The long operation is to wait for a database query

Comment: You could use async/await for it: but then again, that would be a different answer which would not correspond to the question you posed

Comment: Better to disable the button (or event the whole window), show a cursor or other loading UI element and then perform the slow process in a seperate thread. When the thead comes to an end renable your windows using on the UI thread using Dispatcher.Invoke(...